# Xamarin iOS entitlements not published

Tags: xamarin.ios

In Xamarin iOS, when I modify Entitlements.plist and enable Associated Domains or NFC, then archive with an ad-hoc provisioning profile, the resulting .ipa file does not contain the entitlements.

I use this:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- "MyApp.iOS.app"
```

to examine the .ipa.

Entitlement.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:XY.com</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>NDEF</string>
        <string>TAG</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

codesign output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>AAAAAAA.com.XY</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>AAAAAAA</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>AAAAAAA.com.XY</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Why are the entitlements not in the .ipa?

EDIT: I just found out I had not filled in Custom entitlements on the iOS Bundle Signing page in Visual Studio. That may be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to fill in Entitlements.plist. You also have to assign it on the iOS Bundle Signing page -> Custom entitlements.

After I did that, `codesign` shows the correct output (I removed NFC this time)

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>AAAAAAA.com.XY</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>AAAAAAAA</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:XY.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Hi, can you be more explicit on where you have to assign it? I cannot find any "iOS Bundle signing page" in Visual Studio Mac.

Comment: I am using Windows, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify the path of the custom entitlement.plist.

```
codesign --entitlements /path/to/entitlements.plist -s <identity> <code-path>
```

Check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html.

Search the key words `Entitlements` .

Comment: I just found out I had not filled in Custom entitlements on the iOS Bundle Signing page in Visual Studio. That may be the problem.

Comment: I have filled it in and it is stil a problem!